# React Native change the color of a variable within a string

Tags: javascript, react-native, variables

I have a block of text with variables inside of it. I need to change the color of the text variable to differentiate it from the rest of the text, how would I achieve this?

`<Text style={styles.text}>We'll get {recipient} to list anything you should know about the {item}</Text>`

[image]

Comment: Why not wrap `{recipient}` with another `<Text>` element?

Comment: @Unmitigated I could, but there is a lot of them in the following texts, so I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the colour of text within a text component, it is necessary to wrap the string with the different color in another text component.

The code would be as follows:

```
<Text style={styles.text}>
  `We'll get `
  <Text style={{
    color: 'aqua',
    // other styles that you want applied to the text
  }}>{recipient}</Text>
  `to list anything you should know about the ${item}`
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Text style={styles.text}>
`We'll get`
<Text style={styles.variable}>{recipient}</Text>
`to list anything you should know about the`
<Text style={styles.variable}>{item}</Text>
    </Text>
```

You can define the variable style in your styles object like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'black',
  },
  variable: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```